# how can I position objects in raphael.js related to center

Tags: javascript, plot, position, raphael

When I set x, y values to objects to position them on the paper, it measures x, y from the top left corner. Is there any way to change it so that it would position related to the center middle of the paper?

Comment: I think i answered to your question...why would not you accept it?

Comment: you misunderstood the question, it has nothing to do with rectangles

Comment: So then what are u talking about? Clarify your question. Based on the comments after my answer it seemed that you were talking about rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael does not support **g** element. So, you can run an loop and add attribute **transform="translate(*half_of_canvas_width*, *half_of_canvas_height*)"** like this:

```
var paper = new Raphael("canvas");

var cx = 250;
var cy = 250;

var rec = paper.rect(0, 0, 250, 250).attr({fill:'red'})

var list = document.getElementById("canvas").childNodes[0].childNodes;
for(var i = 2 /*because the first two elements are desc tag*/, l = list.length; i < l; i++){
    list[i].setAttribute("transform", "translate(250,250)");
}
```

demo:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/150/

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Raphael has rectangles, circles, and ellipses.

- Latter 2 are positioned with center coordinates, so you have nothing to worry about.
- Rectangle is positioned based on its top left corner coordinates

**So to answer to your question:**

Raphael does not exactly provide a way to position the rectangle with center coordinates.
However you can do that by yourself easily.
Look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/146/)**.

For example:

```
// lets assume your center coordinates are cx and cy
var rec = paper.rect(cx, cy, 120, 80);

// to position in the middle, just do this
var rec = paper.rect(cx - 120/2, cy - 80/2, 120, 80);
```

It is as simple as that. Good luck!

---

**Edit**

If that is what you want to do in your project, then just Raphael.js and override the rectangle class.

Comment: are you sure that it cannot be done without tricking? so there is no official way?

Comment: when you create a rectangle, you initiate it paper.rect(x,y,w,h,r). Look at the documentation: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.rect, x and y are top left coordinates, so NO. But the solution above is perfectly fine

Comment: You can override the `rect` from library to do what you want, but what is wrong with the example above?